# this regex doesn't work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, regex

my condition is:

```
if (/(.{4})/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/(.{4})/g,'$1-');
```

this works only in Mozilla.

whats wrong with this?

i want to add `-` after four digits. for example:
1234567 --> 1234-567

Comment: Tested as working on Chrome (35.0.1916.153/Mac). Can you specify exactly where it doesn't work, and with what results?

Comment: If you are testing for digits only then try `(\d{4})`. Find [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jK9iD2).

Comment: What does "works" and "doesn't work" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be working on Chrome, Safari, Firefox in my testing. One thing to note, is if you end up with an even multiple of four digits, you'll also end up with a trailing dash, so you might want consider a negative lookahead to account for the end of the string (assuming it's all digits); and take into account using `\d` for digits, instead `.`:

```
var value="123456789012";
if (/(\d{4})/g.test(value)) {
    console.log(value.replace(/(\d{4})(?!$)/g,'$1-'));
}
// => "1234-5678-9012"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested below regex [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_regexp_exec) and its working in Firefox, Chrome and IE8 as well.

```
'1234567'.replace(/(\d{4})/g,'$1-')
```

output:

```
1234-567
```

You can test your regex online on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/fK7iJ5)

Comment: `m modifier:` multi-line. I think it is not required in this case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should use \d to find digits.
If you still haven't got any luck with your {}, you could use the "dumb way": /(\d\d\d\d)/g just to see if it makes any difference